# Python general debugging TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string

```
adult = 11
child = 750
(hmtz) = "How many adult tickets would you like?"
(hmtc) = "How many child tickets would you like?"
print (hmtz)
noofa = input()
totad = float(noofa(11))
print (hmtc)
noofc = input()
totch = float(noofc(750))
(finalcost) = totad + totch
print (finalcost)
```

so basically I am coding something that works out the price of cinema tickets. I ran it through and it says something about strings. Please could someone fix the code and explain why.

Comment: Can you explain what `totch = float(noofc(7.50))` is supposed to do? Let's say I entered "23" when I was prompted to enter input on the `noofc = input()` line. What value do you want `totch` to receive?

Comment: it is supposed to make the total of the children tickets so noofc * 750.

Answer (score 3):

```
totad = float(noofa(11))
```

If you're trying to multiply the number of adult tickets (noofa) by the cost of adult tickets (11), you need to use the multiplication operator `*`.

```
totad = float(noofa * 11)
```

And the same for child tickets.

```
totch = float(noofc *7.50)
```

Comment: I changed it and it said: "ParseError: bad input on line 10" @Kevin.             The code I tried was:                                                  adult = 11
child = 750
(hmtz) = "How many adult tickets would you like?"
(hmtc) = "How many child tickets would you like?"
print (hmtz)
noofa = input()
totad = float(noofa * 11)
print (hmtc)
noofc = input()
totch = float(noofc * 750))
(finalcost) = totad + totch
print (finalcost)

Comment: I ran this code through:[ adult = 110
child = 750
(hmtz) = "How many adult tickets would you like?"
(hmtc) = "How many child tickets would you like?"
print (hmtz)
noofa = input()
totad = float((noofa)*(adult))
print (hmtc)
noofc = input()
totch = float((noofc)*(child))
(finalcost) = (totad + totch)/10
print (finalcost).]  IT SAID THE TOTAL WAS INFINITE